# Portable HDD with Ubuntu and Virtual Environments

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, virtual-machines, usb-boot

Wondering if you could offer any advice.

At work I have a MacBook Pro, at home I have a Windows 8 Desktop. I would like to purchase a portable HDD that I can install a USB bootable version of Ubuntu on to replace OS X. If possible I would like to be able to use the portable HDD at home on my Windows 8 machine, but instead of booting into Ubuntu I would like to run it inside a Virtual Environment.

Is this possible, if so what Virtual software would be capable of this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VirtualBox is supporting to boot from a raw device, but first you should create a vmdk file. Look here: https://superuser.com/questions/119237/installing-on-a-physical-drive-with-virtualbox-windows

Comment: Sounds like exactly what i am looking for.. I will give this a try, thanks!